# I have to add the multiple category link in taxonomy field

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, relational

[image]

[image]

Wordpress in acf.

I created taxonomy field to create category link and title
but it doesn't shows in the front end.

Anybody please help me to find a solution. 
Here is my code, but
its not working:

```
<ul>

<?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">View all '<?php echo $term->name; ?>' posts</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

How do u set $terms ?

This is the mark up for the taxonomy field

```
<?php 

$terms = get_field('taxonomy_field_name');

if( $terms ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

        <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>
        <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term ); ?>">View all '<?php echo $term->name; ?>' posts</a>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

If this not works you need to set the id where this fields is stored:

```
$terms = get_field('taxonomy_field_name', $post_id);
```